# Order of things

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say you were in a race, and you finished 5th.
One of your friends comes to you and asks "What was your ___ in the race?".

Or, 'G' is the 6th letter in English alphabet.  Someone asks you what is the ___ of 'G' in English alphabet.

What should come in place of "___" in those sentences?

I thought of "order" maybe, though it doesn't sound correct. Maybe, it shouldn't be asked as in the examples, and should be asked in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

["Position"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/position) is probably the best word for that.

> condition with reference to place; location; situation

Or you could use ["place"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/place?s=t) (especially for sporting events like your first example):

> position, situation, or circumstances: